# Stopping a discord bot from responding to itself

Tags: python, bots, discord

I'm really new to coding, and I'm just wondering if I can get some help with a discord bot I've based off of Frost Bot.

The idea is pretty simple, Frost will respond to users, but I've removed the need to mention it to get a response.
I have a twin bot, too, and the idea is to get them to converse, which they do, however it seems that they're trying to respond to what they themselves have said, which causes a backlog of replies to come out.

Here is the bulk of the code, written in Python- if that matters.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as '+client.user.name+' (ID:'+client.user.id+') | '+str(len(client.servers))+' servers')
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='chat with me!'))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot == client.user:
        await client.send_typing(message.channel)
        txt = message.content.replace(message.server.me.mention,'') if message.server else message.content
        r = json.loads(requests.post('https://cleverbot.io/1.0/ask', json={'user':user, 'key':key, 'nick':'frost', 'text':txt}).text)
        if r['status'] == 'success':
            await client.send_message(message.channel, r['response'] )
```

Any help would seriously be appreciated, as I'm incredibly new to scripting/coding and have spent a few hours already trying to research a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `message.author.id == otherBotID: #stuff` instead.

If you have more than one other bot to have a conversation with, switch to a NOT operator and place it as your own bot's ID, then check if the message author is a bot.

#### EDIT

Replace it in `if not message.author.bot == client.user:`.
Originally, you were checking if the message's author is not a user. And if it was not a user you would do stuff.
But since your own bot is not a user itself, the if statement would pass too when your bot sends a message (and recieves it's own message).

Hence we are placing a if-statement to check if the bot's ID equals to the targeted bot's ID.

Comment: Right now it's just the two bots.

If you don't mind me asking, where can I put the line? Or am I replacing something with it? Sorry, like I said, I'm really new.

Comment: @AtlasMagic I edited my question to add explanation and answer your question

Comment: I saw your edit, and I made the change, although now when I try to launch the bot, it won't start, and I have an error. An "unexpected indent" error, apparently, in the line "await client.send_typing(message.channel)"

Comment: That means you probably indented the `if` statement wrongly when trying to copy it. Just re-indent again. Also if you have no idea what you are copying (the codes), I suggest you look at some basic python tutorial first to at least get a basic understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I realise that may have been silly, but it's been corrected. The First bot currently has that line replaced with "message.author.id == SecondBotID" Is that what you were saying? It now only responds to the second bot, which is exactly what I wanted, however the second bot still responds to itself. If I use the same line of code except with the first bot ID, it should just be mirrored, correct?